# R shiny MathJax Alignment issue

Tags: r, latex, shiny, mathjax

I have a number of rows of equations in my shiny app which I want to align by  their equal sign but can't seem to get the align function to work properly. The code I have is as follows.

```
p("$$\\begin{align}
     \\ x^2 &=  \\text{Chi-Squared}
      \\ sum &= \\text{summation}
      \\ o &=  \\text{the observed values}
      \\ e &=  \\text{the expected values}
      \\end{align}$$")
```

This doesn't work though and I can't figure out how to align them properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not terminated alignment rows.  You need to add `\\\\` at the end of each row (except the last):

```
p("$$\\begin{align}
     \\ x^2 &=  \\text{Chi-Squared} \\\\
     \\ sum &= \\text{summation} \\\\
     \\ o &=  \\text{the observed values} \\\\
     \\ e &=  \\text{the expected values}
     \\end{align}$$")
```

Comment: Thank you very much I couldn't find any shiny examples that used the 4 backslashes. Thank you for your help